# Any ways to recieve sms text messages on desktop without a mobile/smartphone?

Tags: sms, desktop

All the common solutions Ive found online require you to have a smartphone already.

The one solution Ive found that doesnt requires google voice and after spending most of the day managing to get a US number setup (im not in US) and setting it up I am greeted with the message that there has been a problem when trying to pick a number.

Apparently this is common when using DID numbers. Well I dont live in US as I said so have to use them to setup G voice initially. So hit a roadblock there.

Any other solutions? Must be free really. I need to re-verify quite a few accounts daily -which require inputting a code sent via text- and doing it manually on my mobile only allows two but is also tedious so I want to find a way to automate it all thru my computer.

Comment: Google "virtual number" "sms" "windows"

Comment: No it isnt so simple as that. Ofc that was my first port of call but they dont work since theyve already been used by tons of ppl.

Comment: I thought this was obvious - for a unique number you need to pay

Comment: Did you check with twilio ?

Comment: hadnt heard of twilio. Will take a look thanks.